# nodejs program to run puppyteerjs fails

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have written a very simple puppyteerjs program :

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false,
    slowMo: 250 });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.com');
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

  await browser.close();
})();
```

PS D:\js\puppe> node .\screenshot.js
(node:2052) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to launch the browser process!

```
TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md

    at onClose (D:\js\puppe\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Launcher.js:750:14)
    at ChildProcess.helper.addEventListener (D:\js\puppe\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Launcher.js:740:61)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:194:15)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
(node:2052) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:2052) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I tried this program with node version 12 and node version 10, I tried with a headless flag and also giving the path of chrome.exe file from node modules but it keeps on throwing the same exception.

My current environment is: windows 10 and node 10

Comment: add a try catch block and console.log the error first, we don't know the error yet

Comment: Actually I downloaded the latest chromium browser and replaced it with exiting one and it worked